# Why Does Some of My Mesh Get Left Behind?

Tags: mesh, armature, faces

I have a mesh that I parented to an armature, but when I rotate it, some parts get left behind. I'm guessing this is because of how I placed the endpoints of my bones, such that they can't "reach" the parts that are left behind, but I don't know how to fix this.

Does anyone have:

(a) An explanation for why it happens,

AND/OR

(b) A solution?

Comment: Hello, parenting often needs some corrections, but perhaps share your file so that we can test: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: fixing depends on how the bones are assigned to the mesh. if it's with envelopes you might need to increase the envelope size of certain bones. if it's with vertex groups and weight paint, you might need to paint some vertices in